# JQuery Tools Scrollable -- stopping animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable

I have a box that takes an input, then uses the scrollable's `seekTo` method on `keyup` to go to a particular slide. The problem is that if someone types quickly the scrollable gets a large queue and it takes a while for the animation to stop.

What I would like is on `keyup` the previous animation stops (unless the input is empty) and the new animation starts. I've tried putting `.stop()` in various places, but nothing seems to work.

Here is a fiddle of something similar to what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/QaMZH/

Putting a number in the box (ex:1) then changing it to another number (ex: 2) will animate the scrollable to that slide number, but changing the numbers quickly queues a bunch of animations that can take a while to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and after searching for more detailed documentation and fail, I just dug into the code.

It turns out that all you need to do is call this before `.seekTo()`:

```
api.getItemWrap().stop(true, false);
api.seekTo($(this).val(), 1000);
```

where `getItemWrap()` returns the target jQuery element where the animation takes place.

See http://jsfiddle.net/QaMZH/4/ how the modified version works.

This works because `.seekTo()` method calls the jQuery `.animation()` method on the elements, and you can [cancel jQuery animations any time with `.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).